# Error: Config setting for -rpcport only applied on test network when in [test] section

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I'm trying to run bitcoin full node in my PC. I installed bitcoin core, and set path for bitcoind. But whenever I try to run bitcoind, it throws the following error,

```
Error: Config setting for -rpcport only applied on test network when in [test] section.
```

My **bitcoin.conf** file,

```
testnet=1
prune=600
maxconnections=12
maxuploadtarget=20
rpcuser=someusername
rpcpassword=somepassword
rpcport=18332
daemon=0
keypool=10000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't have to specify rpc port in conf file. The bitcoin core will automatically initiate rpc server in 18332 port by default.

But if you wanna try with some other specific port, you need to specify **rpcport** property in a different section meant for test net.

Try this,

```
testnet=1
prune=600
maxconnections=12
maxuploadtarget=20
rpcuser=someusername
rpcpassword=somepassword
daemon=0
keypool=10000

[test]
rpcport=18332
```